# Keymap issue in Atom

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, text-editor, key-bindings

I am trying to edit a keymap in *Atom* editor which will replace "=" symbols with " = ", similar to what inoremap does in vim. I have introduced the following code in **keymap.cson** file.

```
'atom-text-editor':
  '=': 'space-=-space'
```

On doing this, the "=" key stops working. How can I get this behaviour in **Atom** ?

Comment: So in this situation, I think you're misunderstanding how Atom's keymapping works. On the left side you set a hotkey as you did with the `'='`, and on the right side you set the name of an Atom command. You tried to use the command `space-=-space`, but that is not an actual Atom command, so the key stops working. I would recommend looking at the available [`vim`](http://i.imgur.com/RSz2Qpt.png) commands to see if there is something that does what you are trying to do. If you can't find anything that works, try opening an issue on the `vim-mode-plus` package (Assuming that's what you're using).

Comment: What is the theme you are using ?

Comment: It's a custom theme I made. search for `bliss-ui` and `bliss-syntax` on apm.